# How to asynchronously load and update several parts of a UITableView?

Tags: ios, uitableview, asynchronous

I have a table view that is made up of three parts. One part is passed in from the previous view controller, but the other two parts need to be loaded asynchronously. I am displaying "placeholder loading spinners" in the areas that are waiting for HTTP responses. When one section returns, I try updating the table data, but I'm finding that I can get into a situation where both responses return around the same time and try to update the table at the same time, resulting in a crash. It seems like I need to apply some sort of lock and queue so that it does not crash from multiple asynchronous requests trying to update the table at the same time.

I would like to know, what is the iOS best practice for safely loading/updating partial sections of a UITableView asynchronously. I'm not looking for a code sample. Rather, I'm looking for the terminology and method calls that are used to achieve this.

Answer (score 1):

If you're using different sections(and a static number of sections), try reloading them instead of reloading the table view. When an API returns, update its respective section:

`[self.tableView reloadSections: withRowAnimation:]`

Comment: This makes no attempt to answer the question. Don't post comments as an answer.

Comment: Don't get hung up on "sections". It's just 3 different API requests which display data in three different parts of the table. Yes, I think the data source gets updated by the second request before the first one can finish updating the table. That's why I mentioned a lock & queue system, but I'm more curious about the correct approach to solving this problem.

Answer (score 1):

Short answer: main thread. More specifically:

- Update your data model on the main thread
- Reload table view data on the main thread (in fact, do *all* UI stuff on the main thread, always)

If you do the above, you should have no issue.

If you're using something like `NSURLConnection`, you can specify the queue to which the completion proc should be dispatched when data is received (that'd be `NSOperationQueue.mainQueue()`). If you're doing something else that ends up executing on a different thread, you can dispatch back to the main thread with something like `performSelectorOnMainThread` or `dispatch_async` to `dispatch_get_main_queue`.

You *can* reload just particular sections (via `reloadSections:withRowAnimation:`) or even just certain rows (`reloadRowsAtIndexPaths:withRowAnimation:`), but I wouldn't bother with any of that unless/until there's an issue (e.g., slow performance or flicker due to excessive redraw). Start off just reloading the whole table until you've observed that you need to do otherwise.

I know you said you're not looking for a code sample, but I just can't help myself; I communicate better in code than in words.

Main thing is `tableView:cellForRowAtIndexPath:`, which makes a URL request (via `NSURLConnection`). The completion proc (which is dispatched to the main queue) parses some JSON, updates the model, and reloads the table. That's it.

```
class ViewController: UIViewController, UITableViewDataSource {

    @IBOutlet weak var tableView: UITableView!

    private var appIds = [ "391439366", "549762657", "568903335", "327630330", "281796108", "506003812" ]
    private var ratings = [String : Int]() // AppID : RatingCount

    func tableView(tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
        return self.appIds.count;
    }

    func tableView(tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
        let aCell = UITableViewCell(style: .Value2, reuseIdentifier: "RatingCell")
        let appId = appIds[indexPath.row]
        aCell.textLabel?.text = appId
        if let count = self.ratings[appId] {
            // Already got rating count for this app - display it.
            aCell.detailTextLabel!.text = String(count)
            aCell.accessoryView = nil
        }
        else {
            // Don't have rating count: go get it.
            self.getNumberOfRatingsForAppID(appId) {
                success, number in
                if success {
                    // Update model and reload table.
                    self.ratings[appId] = number
                    self.tableView.reloadData()
                }
            }

            // Progress indicator while we wait for data.
            let spinner = UIActivityIndicatorView(activityIndicatorStyle: .Gray)
            spinner.startAnimating()
            aCell.accessoryView = spinner
        }
        return aCell
    }

    typealias GetRatingsCompletion = (Bool, Int) -> ()
    func getNumberOfRatingsForAppID( appID: String, completion: GetRatingsCompletion ) {

        let appStoreURL = NSURL(string: "https://itunes.apple.com/lookup?id=\(appID)")
        let request = NSURLRequest(URL: appStoreURL!)
        NSURLConnection.sendAsynchronousRequest(request, queue: NSOperationQueue.mainQueue() ) {
            response, data, error in

            guard data != nil else {
                completion( false, 0 )
                return
            }

            if let
                jsonResult = (try? NSJSONSerialization.JSONObjectWithData(data!, options:[])) as? NSDictionary,
                results = jsonResult["results"] as? NSArray,
                result = results[0] as? NSDictionary,
                numberOfRatings = result["userRatingCountForCurrentVersion"] as? Int
            {
                completion( true, numberOfRatings )
                return
            }

            completion( false, 0 )
        }
    }

}
```